# Tiled tilemapper - isometric

Tags: tilemap, isometric, tiled

I'm attempting to move from oblique mapping (45 degree angles) to isometric (30 degree angles) in Tiled.

I made a test tile in Photoshop:

[image]

Made an isometric map:

[image]

But my tile appears completely distorted, and the 'isometric' map just appears as a top-down grid rotated 45 degrees:

[image]

How do I create a proper isometric scene using tiled?

---

Hi, in your example ([here](http://forum.mapeditor.org/t/small-howto-create-an-isometric-map/609)), your Tiled grid is angled down. As you can see, mine appears Top down. How do I configure this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When creating your tileset, you need to set up your tileset parameters such that the whole column becomes a single tile. Once you have that working you can tweak the "tile width" and "tile height" properties of your map until your tiles align correctly on the grid.

Easiest is to enable a grid in your image editor so that you can experiment with the size and align the column properly. Then it's easy afterwards to fill in the right values in the New Tileset dialog.

There is a [small HOWTO about creating an isometric map](http://forum.mapeditor.org/t/small-howto-create-an-isometric-map/609) on the forums.

Comment: In tiled, why does the grid appear top down and not at an angle?

Comment: I've added a link to a small HOWTO, which should help with that. Basically you'll usually want to pick a "tile height" that is half your "tile width" for isometric maps. You can tweak these values after creating the map, in Map Properties.

Comment: thanks for this. I've edited my question above. My isometric map is still top down, and not at an angle like you've shown.

Comment: I've already said this in my previous comment. You need to pick a "tile height" that is lower than (usually half of) your "tile width". If you put the same value for "tile width" and "tile height" you get squares. And again, you can tweak these values in the Map Properties so that you can immediately see how this affects the grid.